# Code with double pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, double

So, in class we've been given this program in C:

```
int main() {
    int num;                                
    int *ptr; 
    int **handle;

    num = 14;                           
    ptr = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));   
    handle = &ptr;

    **handle = num;                     
    *(*handle+1) = num+1;                   
    *ptr = num-2;                           
    ptr = &num;                         
    *ptr = soma_ds(num-2)
```

What I understood from it was:

1.An integer, a pointer and a double pointer are declared

1. `num = 14;` assings the value 14 to num
2. `ptr = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` reserves in memory a block for a two-integer array assigned to ptr

4.Then `handle = &ptr;` assigns the value of the address of ptr to handle (meaning that handle points to ptr?)

5.And then `**handle = num;` confuses me, but I interpreted it as: the pointer to which handle is pointing (that would be ptr) is now pointing to num (14). **Question:** if this is correct, then what would be the effect of this operation, given that ptr is assigned the memory space of an array?

6.After this I'm pretty sure I'm getting all of it wrong. So the line `*(*handle+1) = num+1` would mean, since handle has the address of ptr, that *handle+1 (*handle being ptr, therefore *handle+1 would be the increment of num's memory address) would be now pointing to num+1 (14+1=15). **Question:** if this is correct, would that mean that the array reserved to ptr is now composed by the integers 14 and 15 on a row?

7.Then `*ptr = num-2;´; I assumed that would affect the variable num itself, working as`num = num - 2;` and therefore changing its value to 12. So, at this point, we'd have ptr pointing to the array composed of 14 and 15 and num having the value 12.

**Question:** I must be thinking wrong, because I can't understand what the next command, `ptr = &num;`, does. Would anyone be able to explain it/ provide a link or an example that would help me understand it?

Thank you!

Comment: Tell you lecture it should be `ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @EdHeal It needs a cast

Comment: @Velnna - sounds like you have it figured out okay to me

Comment: @Rob; *It needs a cast*: No. It doesn't

Comment: have they changed the standard to allow void * to be assigned to int *?

Comment: @Rob, it does not need a cast. Do you have any warning without the cast? No. If you do have a warning it's because you forgot to include stdlib (or you are doing C++).

Comment: @Rob You need the cast in C++, and in C++ only. In C (and the question is tagged as a C question), you can implicitely convert any pointer to and from a `void*`. This is one of the few points where C++ is not a strict superset of C.

Comment: ... anyway using C++ should not be using `malloc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "4. ... meaning that handle points to ptr?"

yes! ok.

> "5. And then **handle = num; confuses me, but I interpreted it as: the pointer to which handle is pointing (that would be ptr) is now pointing to num"

Not correct: here there is the assignment of the value of `num` to (ie: `num` is copied into) *the location pointed by the location pointed by `handle`*. The *location pointed by `handle`* is `ptr` per the previous line, so `num` is copied into the the *location pointed by `ptr`*, that is the 1st of the two location allocated with `malloc()`.

> "6. ... would be now pointing to num+1"

the conclusion is correct, but you are not *pointing to `num+1`*. You have assigned/copied `num+1` into `*(*handle+1)`. Since `*handle` is `ptr`, into `*(ptr+1)` or if you prefer the effect is the same of `ptr[1]=num+1` - where `ptr` is still pointing to the memory allocated with `malloc()`.

> "7.Then *ptr = num-2; I assumed that would affect the variable num itself, working asnum = num - 2;` and therefore changing its value to 12. So, at this point, we'd have ptr pointing to the array composed of 14 and 15 and num having the value 12.

nope: read "*" as "the object pointed by" - it's a good mnemonic. So you are still altering *the object pointed by `ptr`*, that is `ptr[0] = num-2`, you are changing again the first of the two integer locations allocated with `malloc()`.

Only at the next line (`ptr = &num;`) you are changing the value of `ptr` to the address of `num` and operations on `*ptr`, *the object pointed by `ptr`*, are going to affect `num` now on.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` will become the address of `num` i.e. where 14 is stored

Answer (score 0):

5.And then **handle = num; confuses me, but I interpreted it as: the pointer to which handle is pointing (that would be ptr) is now pointing to num (14). Question: if this is correct, then what would be the effect of this operation, given that ptr is assigned the memory space of an array?

```
The above statement means you can access the num value using **handle
```